# Why not use \cr instead of \\ in tables?

Tags: tables, siunitx

In plain TeX `\cr` is used to mark the end of a row in a table.
In LaTeX `\\` is usually used instead.

`\\` takes an optional argument, which `\cr` does not support. But I never use that anyway, I prefer booktabs' `\addlinespace`.

As I have found out recently `\\` does not always work, see [this bug](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/53) which was closed with [this commit](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/commit/36fb4555c2d959c21446357dfcae52e8eb758145) which adds a subsection to the documentation explaining that `\cr` should be used instead. If the last column of a table is a `S` column (defined by the `siunitx` package) and text is appended to this column (with the `array` package's `<{...}` syntax) the spacing is wrong when using `\\` but correct when using `\cr`.

So I am wondering: Why not always use `\cr` instead of `\\` to denote the end of a row in a table?

Comment: one advantage of `\\ ` is that it facilitates some constructions of tabular contents because TeX does not see the hidden `\cr`. In fact one sometimes wishes the `&` too had been abstracted by LaTeX.

Comment: The definition of \\ changes with different environments.  Not just `tabular` and `array`, but also environments like `center`.

Comment: Also, \\ can take an optional argument (vertical space), whereas `\cr` does not.

Comment: Bottom line of course is I should fix this in `siunitx` ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The argument against using `\cr` is really the generic argument that applies to any use of undocumented internal interfaces in any software.

`\cr` is not a documented latex command, the documented commands to end table rows are `\\` and `\tabularnewline`.

In the default implementation, if you are not using the `*` form or `[]` argument, `\\` basically just does `\cr` so using `\cr` directly comes to the same thing. However as it isn't a documented latex command the implementation of tables could change so that they were not equivalent, also conversions of latex to html etc have no reason to expect to see `\cr` in a document and so may fail.

If some package has a bug that means `\cr` is needed then that's a bug that should be fixed, or if some package defines an environment where `\cr` is expected then it is that package documentation not latex documentation (or this answer) that says if you should use it.