# How can I define a macro to conditionally insert a `\multicolumn`?

Tags: tables, expansion, latex3

I need to define a macro which can insert a table row containing a `\multicolumn`.
It should decide whether to insert it by evaluating some LaTeX3 code on its argument.

Here is a minimal non-working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_clist { foo, bar }

\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\MaybeATableRow}{m}{%
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_tmpa_clist { #1 }
    {\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}\cr}
    {}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \MaybeATableRow{foo}
    A & B \\
    \MaybeATableRow{qux}
    X & Y \\
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This gives a well known error:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit
                   \@multispan
l.20     \MaybeATableRow{foo}
```

To my understanding, this is caused by the presence of non-expandable code before the `\multicolumn` which causes the premature start of the cell.

In this case the non expandable macro (according to the manual) is `\clist_if_in:NnTF`.

In my real use case the logic is much more complex and I can't give up complex data structures like `clist`s (virtually all relevant macros are not expandable).

Is there some way to define such a macro?

Comment: Avoid `\DeclareExpandableNewCommand` and prefer `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`. Also use ``\\`` instead of `\cr`.

Comment: Sure, thanks. For anyone reading: `\DeclareExpandableNewCommand` VS `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` is explained in @egreg's answer below while `\\` VS `\cr` is explained in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/433527/82186

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variant to Skillmon's answer.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_clist { foo, bar }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\MaybeATableRow}{m}
 {
  \noalign
   {
    \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_tmpa_clist { #1 }
     {
      \cs_gset:Npn \__paolo_mc: {\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}\\}
     }
     {
      \cs_gset_eq:NN \__paolo_mc: \prg_do_nothing:
     }
    \group_insert_after:N \__paolo_mc:
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \MaybeATableRow{foo}
  A & B \\
  \MaybeATableRow{qux}
  X & Y \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The `\noalign` is needed in order not to start a new row. It forms an implicit group, so we can smuggle outside it something using `\group_insert_after:N` (that is, `\aftergroup`).

Avoid `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand`, because it doesn't check whether the command is defined. Also `\cr` should be `\\`.

Comment: What's the reason to do `\group_insert_after:N` instead of just putting it after the closing brace here?

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to put unexpandable code inside of a `\noalign`, but this way your code can only be placed at the start of a line and has to build the entire line (as is the case in your MWE).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_gset:Nn \g_tmpa_clist { foo, bar }

\cs_new:Npn \paolo_noalign_start:
  {
    \tex_noalign:D { \if_int_compare:w 0 = `} \fi:
  }  
\cs_new:Npn \paolo_noalign_end:
  {
    \if_int_compare:w 0 = `{ \fi: }
  }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\MaybeATableRow}{m}{%
  \paolo_noalign_start:
  \clist_if_in:NnTF \g_tmpa_clist { #1 }
    {
      \paolo_noalign_end:
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}\cr
    }
    { \paolo_noalign_end: }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \MaybeATableRow{foo}
    A & B \\
    \MaybeATableRow{qux}
    X & Y \\
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can simply use `\noalign\bgroup` to start and `\egroup` to finish. No need for brace tricks here.

Comment: @egreg why does the LaTeX kernel use brace tricks in that case instead of `\bgroup` and `\egroup` (for example in `\hline`)?

Comment: Mainly because the braces need to be supplied in different macros, I'd say.